# Keeping it in comma order

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to get the value to stay in a comma order like 123,456,789 when subtracting the value. Here is the current code:

```
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim health As Integer
    health = lblHPPlayer.Text
    lblHPPlayer.Text = Val(health) - 1000
End Sub
```

'That is the value of what I wanna change*

lblHPPlayer.Text = "9,850,000"

Comment: Create a form-level property called `Health`. You can make it private. Now any time you need to update `Heath` then also update the text in `lblHPPlayer`. That way you never need to parse the text - it only ever just shows you the value of a proper integer property.

Comment: Alright, I am new to VB and I am doing this as a Final project so could you explain what that means please?

Comment: I've posted an answer showing the code.

Comment: Thank you. So what is the .tostring("NO")? I thought it was a troll saying that.

Comment: The `.ToString("N0")` converts the integer into a string with commas.

Comment: So then it automatically knows the order of which to put a comma then?

Comment: Do you mean does it know to put a comma in to group each lot of three digits starting at the right hand side? Then, yes.

Comment: Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a form-level property called `Health`. You can make it private. Now any time you need to update `Heath` then also update the text in `lblHPPlayer`. That way you never need to parse the text - it only ever just shows you the value of a proper integer property.

Something like this:

```
Private _health As Integer

Public Property Health() As Integer
    Get
        Return _health
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Integer)
        _health = value
        lblHPPlayer.Text = _health.ToString("N0")
    End Set
End Property

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Me.Health -= 1000
End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

Use the numeric format specifier.

```
lblHPPlayer.Text = (Val(health) - 1000).toString("N0")
```

Comment: This answers too.